# returning json data after sending Form Data using Ajax JQuery shows json data only and doesn't call the on success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

This is my Ajax on click event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('add.button').on('click', function() {
        let title = $('#add-project-input').val()
        let content = $('#add-project-description').val()
        let deadline = $('#add-project-deadline').val()

        request = $.ajax({
            url: '/add-project',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                title: title,
                content: content,
                deadline: deadline
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                background.style.opacity = "0"
                background.style.visibility = "hidden"
                projectModal.classList.toggle("active")
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    })
})
```

This is my Flask route

```
@app.route("/add-project", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def add():

    if request.method == "POST":
        input_title = request.form['title']
        input_content = request.form['content']
        input_deadline = request.form['deadline']
            
        
        project = Project(title = input_title, key=generate_password_hash(input_title), content = input_content, deadline = input_deadline, author=current_user)
        db.session.add(project)
        db.session.commit()
        return json.dumps({"status" : "OK"}) 
    return redirect('/')
```

Whenever I submit a button the page reloads and this is what it shows [{'status':'ok'}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXGWY.png)

What I wanted was for it to return the json response and then call the success function. Is there a reason why its doing this?

Comment: I would assume the `add.button` element is `type="submit"` so your parent `form` element is causing a normal browser HTTP request and redirecting the page. You probably need to call `preventDefault()` on the event that's raised - ideally by hooking the JS event handler to the `submit` of the form, not the `click` of the button

Comment: I did what you said. I changed the event from button.on(click) to form.on(submit) and added a preventDefault but it still didnt work.

Comment: Does explicitly setting the status code to 200 change anything? Try replacing `return json.dumps(...)` with `return jsonify({'status':'ok'}),200`. You'll need to import this with `from flask import jsonify`.

Comment: Im sorry if I wasn't able to reply. I got into a motorcycle accident and I've spent these few weeks on crutches as my leg had been placed on a cast. I Also had wide skin abrasions all over my body which made coding challenging so I focused on resting first.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the answer. I repeatedly watched Flask Ajax tutorial on youtube and I found out that they did not place both the method and action on the form and left it empty.

like this,

```
<form>
   <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

since, both url and type are already placed inside ajax.

I didn't place my html form in the issue above as I thought it doesn't have anything to do with it. A dumb mistake on my part.

Im still new to this and I didnt know that this is how It should be done. Atleast the issue have been solved.